# Sources.list Critical Vulnerability link update

Tags: apt, updates, security

This question is related to [this GitHub post](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/releases/tag/23.09.1).

I just wanted to make sure if I got the link correctly and not made an error I replace the ma.archiveUbuntu links with http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

[image: screenshot]

Is this correct, or do I do to do something else?

Comment: FYI for future reference, it is better to copy/paste from terminal to the post as text instead of linking screenshots from terminal.  It's more readable for people that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are focusing only on the Security repos, then you can combine them all in one line:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

So long as you have the following for the rest of your repos (note I do NOT include the Partner repo here at the moment):

```
deb http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://ma.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

That should meet most of the needs.

(Note I assume you left the partner repo, if enabled, alone.  I also included the commented out `deb-src` lines in case you need them in the *future* at some point.)